# import frameworks gives error after adding delegates

Tags: swift

I have been trying to import StoreKit and GameKit to my xcode project. Each time I try to do so I receive an error. The error says : GameViewController does not conform to protocol ".." after I import the frame work and add the delegates to the class. Anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must all implement the required delegate method of the StoreKit & GameKit.

Good luck